# copy legend in Dojo charts

Tags: dojo, legend, dojox.charting

I am using dojox charts in my project.

On right click and selecting 'copy', at the chart area, copies the chart but I also want the legend to be copied.

I created legend as a separate html element and chart area as a separate element.

How do I go about it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Copying is not a functionality of chart, it is implemented by some browsers natively. It is up to you to provide the copy functionality for a legend.

Comment: oh okay, so how do i provide copy functionality for the legend?

Comment: Exactly the same way you do it for any HTML object.